# No drop with basic gongsolution sample

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, mvvm-light

I am trying to implement the drag and drop function from gongsolutions in a simple WPF MVVM Light sample but I can't get it to work..I can drag the items (it goes into the event) but cannot drop them. I get the unavailable mouse icon instead of being able to drop it.

This is the xaml:

```
    xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop;assembly=GongSolutions.Wpf.DragDrop" 

        <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal" >

        <ListView Width="200" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
                  dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" AllowDrop="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}" />

        <ListView Width="200" DisplayMemberPath="EmployeeName" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" 
                  dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" AllowDrop="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

and this is my viewmodel:

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDropTarget
{

    private ObservableCollection<Model.Customer> _Customers;
    public ObservableCollection<Model.Customer> Customers
    {
        get
        {
            return _Customers;
        }
        set
        {
            _Customers = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Customers");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Model.Employee> _Employees;
    public ObservableCollection<Model.Employee> Employees
    {
        get
        {
            return _Employees;
        }
        set
        {
            _Employees = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Employees");
        }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {

        Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

        Customers.Add(new Model.Customer { Name = "Company A" });
        Customers.Add(new Model.Customer { Name = "Company B" });
        Employees.Add(new Model.Employee { EmployeeName = "Tom" });
        Employees.Add(new Model.Employee { EmployeeName = "Jos" });
    }

    ////public override void Cleanup()
    ////{
    ////    // Clean up if needed

    ////    base.Cleanup();
    ////}

    public void DragOver(DropInfo dropInfo)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dropInfo.Data.ToString());
    }

    public void Drop(DropInfo dropInfo)
    {

    }
}
```

Sample project: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=A8B989CA62E8B39C&id=A8B989CA62E8B39C%21103

Comment: Did you try to set the dropInfo.Effects property to DragDropEffects.Move (or something else) in the DragOver handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your target has to set a DragDropEffect in the DragOver handler to allow the drop:

```
public void DragOver(DropInfo dropInfo)
{
    dropInfo.Effects = System.Windows.DragDropEffects.Move;
}
```